# No output from compiler

Tags: typescript

I am trying to invoke the Typescript compiler (on Windows via node) with the following command-line:

```
tsc.cmd -p tsconfig.json --outDir D:\ts-cscript-debugger\out
```

The current working folder -- and the location of the `tsconfig.json` -- is `D:\DefinitelyTyped\types\activex-wia`.

However, the compiler doesn't output anything; the folder passed to `outDir` remains empty.

**Why? How can I get the compiler to output the compiled files?**

---

When I pass the `--listFiles` parameter, I get a list of all the files to be compiled:

```
C:/Users/-----/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.scripthost.d.ts
C:/Users/-----/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
D:/DefinitelyTyped/types/activex-wia/index.d.ts
D:/DefinitelyTyped/types/activex-wia/activex-wia-tests.ts
```

---

The `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "scripthost"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "noEmit": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "files": [
        "index.d.ts",
        "activex-wia-tests.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` contains `"noEmit": true,` which specifically instructs the compiler not to emit the Javascript code.

Comment: !!! I don't believe I missed that! NB This behavior can be overridden from the command line with `--noEmit false` [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10967).

Answer (score 5):

I experienced similar behavior but the `noEmit` answer didn't help me (because I hadn't set that flag).

In my case, the issue was that I had manually deleted my `dist/` directory but neglected to also delete the `.tsbuildinfo` file, putting it out of sync. TypeScript checked the `.tsbuildinfo` and determined that it had nothing to do as it believed all of the source files were up to date.

Deleting `.tsbuildinfo` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Delete `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file works